# Пропуск несуществующих элементов

Tags: perl

Разбираю сложную структуру. Необходимо вытащить данные из хеша хешей. Интересующий меня момент выглядит приблизительно так:

```
print exists $v -> {'field'} -> {'code'} ? $v -> {'field'} -> {'code'} : 0;
```

Нутром чую, что можно урезать эту запись, может кто подсказать как?

Comment: Вынос `$v -> {'field'}` перед этим в отдельную переменную не в счет?

Comment: Ничего странного не вижу. Контекст явно оторван от жизни и не прогонялся через Devel::NytProf. Ф топку.

Comment: @Regent, не совсем то, что хочется. Структура на самом деле несколько сложнее, разбор json, это пример.

Comment: @Pivoter, ну так покажите реальность. А то непонятны ваши цели и задачи. Может, у вас там архитектура такая, что позволяет врать про "write-only" перла... Или для вас любая структура с парой уровней - сложная, так это совсем другой вопрос.

Comment: @Pivoter так даже если и сложнее, то вынести в переменную всю цепочку кроме последнего ключа всё равно можно. А про функцию `returnIfExistsOrZero` я не слышал.

Comment: @Mike это ломает проверку существования ключа. Если `{'code'}` равен, например, пустой строке, то в вашем примере будет выведен 0.

Comment: @pink-tux, не вижу смысла в никому не нужных подробностях. Я всего лишь хочу знать, можно ли проверить существование и забрать значение внутреннего хеша на одном-единственном шаге.

Comment: @Mike, если проверку опустить, то вот - _Use of uninitialized value in print at ... line 101._

Comment: @Mike, ваш вариант - то, что я искал. Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
print $v -> {'field'} -> {'code'} // 0;
```

оператор `// 0` - дает ноль когда левый операнд не определен (undef)

Comment: Стоит отметить, что `// 0` - это не полная замена `exists`: можно использовать, только если в хэше нет значений, равных `undef`.